# Regex for extracting id and name from string

Tags: php, regex

I need to extract id and name from the following string.

```
$string = $data[1][0];

preg_match('/NAME\s+:([^ID]+)(ID\s+:)(.+)/', $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

The above expression works when I have tried online tools but it's not working in the script only when getting value from the array.

String value is

```
$string = 'NAME      : KARL JOHNSON ID        : 12345 (LGW FA-319,320 ) ';
```

Comment: This is [never going to work](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) (at least not reliably) - someone could literally be called `ID:` if they wanted.

Comment: aren't there some hidden `\n` in the string? With this string you can't really tell what's a key and what's a value.

Comment: if you are sure the format will always be as in your example, why not splice the content after the colons, stopping at any double space?

Comment: @DevinFields Can you elaborate that?

Comment: @CD001Do you have any better approach for that?

Comment: match the last `ID:` of the string

Comment: I would like store any part after the NAME: and ID:

Comment: [see](https://regex101.com/r/bsD1ES/1)

Comment: `[^ID]+` probably does not do what you expect. It's a negated character class and matches characters that are neither `I` nor `D`. To find the culprit please show the exact data that fails, as your sample data is [actually working with your code](https://eval.in/1043292). Here is [another regex idea](https://regex101.com/r/8GlZMD/1).

Comment: Here given solutions works fine when I pass the string but somehow it doesn't work when I extract the same sample data from HTML page. Strange !! Encoding issue?

Comment: @bobblebubble It's same as sample data which I'm extracting from the HTML page.

Comment: @Suraj there might be some characters (like a linefeed \n \r, a tab) in between in the original source. Try adding `[\s]*` before the ID group

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments by @CD001 this could never work, but here is pattern that may satisfy your needs:

```
NAME +: +([a-zA-Z ]+)ID +: *(.+)
```

First captured group is the name, second is the ID.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XtD3wm/2)

Comment: It works fine but when I fetch the same value as sample data from an array it gives me an empty array. Not sure whats going wrong.

Comment: Did you try looping through array and matching one element at a time?

Comment: I fetched the value from the array and I did print and make sure it is the same as sample data. As it is the only value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt:

```
preg_match('/NAME\s+: ([A-Z ]+) ID\s+: ([0-9]+ )\([A-Z0-9 \-,]+\)/', $string, $matches);

$name = $matches[1];
$id = $matches[2];
```

The complete output:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($matches, true) . '</pre>';

Array
(
    [0] => NAME      : KARL JOHNSON ID        : 12345 (LGW FA-319,320 )
    [1] => NAME      : 
    [2] => KARL JOHNSON
    [3] =>  ID        : 
    [4] => 12345 
    [5] => (LGW FA-319,320 )
)
```

*This may not be optimized, I'm training on RegEx actually.*

Comment: Your solution only gives me ID but name contains the ID word

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood !